# Multiple LINQ to SQL queries. Enumeration optimisation

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a list of ~ 15,000 'team's that need an individual linq query to return results.

Namely - [Select the last 10 games for 'team']

```
public IEnumerable<ResultsByDate> SelectLast10Games(DateTime date, string team)
        {
            return
            (   from e in db.E0s
                where e.DateFormatted < date &&
                (e.HomeTeam == team || e.AwayTeam == team)
                orderby e.Date descending
                select new ResultsByDate
                {
                    Date = e.Date,
                    HomeTeam = e.HomeTeam,
                    AwayTeam = e.AwayTeam,
                    HomeGoals = e.FTHG,
                    AwayGoals = e.FTAG
                }
            ).Take(10);
        }
```

This query is probably fine, it seems fast enough when called 15,000 times.

My real issue is that I have to enumerate each query and this really kills the performance.

For each of these queries I need to run a method on the 10 results and hence the queries need enumerating.

The question is how can I avoid 15,000 enumerations?

I thought about placing each of the results into a big list and **then** calling .ToList() or whatever's best, but adding to a List enumerates as it goes along so this doesn't seem viable.

Is there a way to combine all 15,000 LINQ queries into one giant LINQ query such as..

```
public IEnumerable<ResultsByDate> SelectLast10Games(DateTime date, List<string> Teams)
        {
            foreach(var team in Teams)
            { var query = 
                  (from e in db.E0s
                   where e.DateFormatted < date &&
                   (e.HomeTeam == team || e.AwayTeam == team)
                   orderby e.Date descending
                   select new ResultsByDate
                   {
                     Date = e.Date,
                     HomeTeam = e.HomeTeam,
                     AwayTeam = e.AwayTeam,
                     HomeGoals = e.FTHG,
                     AwayGoals = e.FTAG
                   }
                   ).Take(10);
            }
        }
```

So this would return one huge result set that I can then enumerate in one go and work from there?

I have tried but I can't seem to get the LINQ loop correct ( if it's even possible - and the best way to fix my issue).

The whole program takes ~ 29 minutes to complete. Without the enumeration its around 30 seconds which is not amazing but satisfactory given the criteria.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplish with using `Teams.Select(team => ..)`

```
var query = Teams
                .Select(team =>
                    db.E0s
                    .Where(e => e.DateFormatted < date && (e.HomeTeam == team || e.AwayTeam == team))
                    .OrderByDescending(e => e.Date)
                    .Select(
                        e =>
                        new ResultsByDate {
                             Date = e.Date,
                             HomeTeam = e.HomeTeam,
                             AwayTeam = e.AwayTeam,
                             HomeGoals = e.FTHG,
                             AwayGoals = e.FTAG
                        }
                    )
                    .Take(10)
            )
```

If you're looking for best performance for heavily querying, you should consider using **SQL Stored Procedure** and calling it using *ADO.NET*, *Dapper* or *EntityFramework* (The order of choices is from the optimal to the trivial) My recommendation is using **Dapper**. This will speed up your query, especially if the table is indexed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To feed 15k parameters efficiently into server, You can use TVP:
http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/01/sql-2008-tvp-table-valued-parameters.html

> My real issue is that I have to enumerate each query and this really
>   kills the performance.

Unless You enumerate the result, there is no call to the server. So no wonder it is fast without enumeration. But that does not mean that the enumeration is the problem.